# Color line, but don't show the matched pattern

Tags: sed, colors

So i have this text:

```
2019/06/16 22:36:28 (UNIVERSE) * @{EE3F}Trytrytry sagt: @{F80F}going afk for a bit
```

I want to color the whole line in red for example. Then remove the unecessary parts to:

```
22:36:28 Trytrytry sagt: going afk for a bit
```

The removing of the parts is works already, but when i add:

```
norm="$(printf '\033[0m')"
boldred="$(printf '\033[0;1;31m')" 
sed -ue s/UNIVERSE/${boldred}&${norm}/g
```

It only colorize UNIVERSE and show it up, but i don't want let it show. I want to color the whole line where UNIVERSE was. So just adding color. So lets say:

IF (UNIVERSE) THEN color the line red in terminal, but let it be clean and don't show up the removed parts.

Any ideas?

Comment: *The removing of the parts is works already* please show what you mean by *unnecessary parts* and how you remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `sed` line, for this one:

`sed -ue 's/\(.*UNIVERSE.*\)/'${boldred}'\1'${norm}'/g'`

with `.*UNIVERSE.*`, you are matching any whole line that contains `UNIVERSE` on it; then, you add the parentheses: `\(.*UNIVERSE.*\)` to capture the match (the whole line in this case), and then, you backreference  your previous match with `\1`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked very good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should:

1. match lines containing your search string `/UNIVERSE/`
2. remove the *unnecessary parts*
3. replace beginning `(^)` with `${boldred}`
4. replace end (`$`) with `${norm}`

Here's a tentative snippet that should show you the way, based on the posted specifications:

```
norm="$(printf '\033[0m')"; boldred="$(printf '\033[0;1;31m')"; sed -ure "/UNIVERSE/{s/^[^ ]* //;s/\(UNIVERSE[^}]+}//;s/sagt:[^}]+}/sagt: /;s/^/${boldred}/;s/$/${norm}/}" input1
```

Or, split for readability:

```
norm="$(printf '\033[0m')";
boldred="$(printf '\033[0;1;31m')";
sed -ure "/UNIVERSE/ {
    s/^[^ ]* //;
    s/\(UNIVERSE[^}]+}//;
    s/sagt:[^}]+}/sagt: /;
    s/^/${boldred}/;
    s/$/${norm}/
}"
```

---

I'm also providing a full, self-contained Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants)} if(/UNIVERSE/){s/^\S*\s//;s/\(UNIVERSE[^}]+}//;s/sagt:[^}]+}/sagt: /;$_=RED.$_.RESET}'
```

Or, split for readability:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants)}
    if (/UNIVERSE/) {
        s/^\S*\s//;
        s/\(UNIVERSE[^}]+}//;
        s/sagt:[^}]+}/sagt: /;
        $_ = RED . $_ . RESET
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` line in this snippet matches against `UNIVERSE` and then applies the `red`+`bold` attributes to the entire line. I've used `tput` to obtain the attribute values because it adapts depending on the terminal type (including where one isn't set, such as in a `cron` job):

```
# See "man 5 terminfo" for other portable settings
red=$(tput setaf 1 2>/dev/null)
bold=$(tput bold 2>/dev/null)
norm=$(tput sgr0 2>/dev/null)

# Perform the substitution
sed -e "/UNIVERSE/s/^.*$/${red}${bold}&${norm}/"
```